# Short story about the rediscovery of math

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recall a science fiction short story where computers are so integrated that people have forgotten how to do basic math, until someone "rediscovers" it. The government then makes plans to put humans inside bombs to guide them, because "you can always replace a person, but you can't replace a computer" (probably paraphrased).

Anyone know it's title?

Comment: It is. Thank you. I will remove the thread.

Comment: Dupes are ok, no need to delete.  You probably won't get upvotes, but probably not downvotes, either.

Comment: It’s fine (and often useful) to have duplicates for story-ID questions. People will remember different aspects of the story – having multiple descriptions that lead back to the same answer makes it more likely somebody finds what they’re looking for.